# Process a heavy function by GPU in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, gpu

I have a heavy function in C# that process an image with image processing, How can I run it on GPU?

Comment: You can google "gpgpu api for c#" or "gpgpu for c#" or even "c# gpu acceleration". Cudafy seems good by "directly" running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using one of the NET CIL/GPU compilers: Alea GPU (http://www.aleagpu.com) or Altimesh (http://www.altimesh.com/). They work and but have some limitations. I have been developing Campy (http://campynet.com/), a free and open source compiler that will work with most NET frameworks, but it's not yet ready. You will need to parallelize your code in any case. You could use Cudafy (https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=cudafy), but I would not recommend it since it has not been updated since April 2015, and does not support CUDA 8 or 9.